# Income and Expense calculation

Tags: mysql

I need to show income and expense per day

Income and expenses are different table

I need to show in following format, for ex:

17/08/2019 date have two incomes in the table

I need to calculate sum of the income in the date, showing on the result with the same day expense.

I have tried with some queries, but it's not working.

```
Date |  Income | Expense | Profit 

Select SUM(d.amount)
     , SUM(e.amount)
     , d.date
     , e.date 
  FROM due d 
  JOIN expenses e
    ON d.date = e.date
```

Expense table -table-name : expenses

```
id | date      |  details  |  amount
1   13-08-2019     daily      50
2   17-08-2019     cleaning   50
3   17-08-2019     cleaning   50
4   18-08-2019     Tea        150 
5   18-08-2019     other      50
```

Income table -table-name : due

```
id | date         |  amount
4   12-08-2019        150
5   13-08-2019        100 
6   18-08-2019        450
7   18-08-2019        50
```

result will be:

```
id | date       | Income | Expense | Profit
1    12-08-2019   150       NULL      150
2    13-08-2019   100       50        50
3    17-08-2019   NULL      100       -100
4    18-08-2019   500       200       300
```

Comment: Step 1. Store dates using a date data type. Step 2. See UNION.

Comment: And note that this isn't 'per day'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, I'd suggest posting some table details by using `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` which will allow us to better assist you.

You should be able to use a union and some grouping to get what you are after:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    SUM(Income) as Income,
    SUM(Expense) as Expense,
    SUM(Income) - SUM(Expense) as Profit
FROM (
    SELECT
        due.date as Date,
        due.amount as Income,
        0 as Expense
    FROM due
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        expenses.date as Date
        0 as Income,
        expenses.amount as Expense
    FROM expenses
)
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. but i am getting the following issue after run the query.                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                             
   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0 as Income,
        expenses.amount as Expense
    FROM expenses
)
GROUP BY' at line 15

Comment: Now i  have made some corrections , it is working                                                                                      SELECT Date, SUM(Income) as Income, SUM(Expense) as Expense, SUM(Income) - SUM(Expense) as Profit FROM ( SELECT due.date as Date, due.amount as Income, 0 as Expense FROM due UNION ALL SELECT expenses.date as Date, 0 as Income, expenses.amount as Expense FROM expenses ) as vij GROUP BY Date